# Metal App FPS drops in Debug but fine in Instruments while profiling

Tags: ios, xcode, core-animation, instruments, metal

I am using Metal for rendering live video frames plus some custom control (a circular slider) for zooming that I implemented using Quartz 2D API. When I run the app in debugger, I see FPS drop from 30 to sometimes 11 and zoom is not smooth on older devices such as iPad Mini 2. I then run the code in Time Profiler and surprisingly, there is no fps drop in Time Profiler. App runs smooth in Profiler. How do I know what is causing fps drop in debug?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the [Metal Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Dev-Technique/Dev-Technique.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH8-SW3) layer that's active for your debug scheme. It's not typically surprising that performance of programs is worse in general when debugging (due to lack of optimizations, or asserts being enabled, etc.).

If you want to get similar Metal performance when debugging, you can try disabling the Metal Validation in the scheme settings. But, then, of course, you lose the actual debugging benefit of the validation of your use of Metal.

Comment: Didn't make any difference unfortunately. What else to try?

Comment: I have a bigger set of observations for MTKView vs GLKView, and also in debug vs profile vs release versions. Will post a separate question.

Comment: Here is link to new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362049/mtkview-vs-glkview-performance-on-old-devices